# How to properly ignore exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception

We all write from time to time code like this:

```
try {
  // ... some code.
} catch (SomeException e) {
  // ... No action is required, just ignore.
}
```

Is there any standard code fragment like annotation to show we really intend to ignore exception? Something that shows to other team members and static analyzers we really need to skip this situation like `InterruptedException` after `Thread.sleep()`? Something like:

```
Exception.ignore(e);
```

Googled around but have not found something standard for such case.

This is especially relevant to tests that assure exceptions:

```
try {
    action();
    fail("We expected this to fail.");
} catch (ExpectedException e) {
    ignore(e, "OK, so far so good.");
}
```

Comment: Why is empty catch statement or one with comment not enough ?

Comment: The way that you have done it is the standard way that it is done in Java.  Scala has been seeing an increase in using a functional technique that would now work in Java8.  http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html

Comment: Regarding to log & forget - yes, usually it is the best way. But in rare cases you don't want even logging here.

Comment: @RomanNikitchenko, It would be a _very_ rare case where `LOGGER.debug(e)` is not acceptable.

Comment: You could write some static helper method like `IgnoreException.ignore(Exception e)`, which could do some logging, or do nothing at all. This way it's clear that it should be ignored, and your analyzer should be satisfied, too.

Comment: @tobias_k Exactly what I'm trying to get but some 'standard' approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to ignore an exception is to catch & swallow it, being very specific on the exception of course, you wouldn't want to catch `Exception e`, that would be a very bad idea.

```
try{
  ...  //code
}
catch( VerySpecificException ignore){
   Log(ignore);
}
```

Logging is obviously optional but a good practice.

Comment: By the way - it's good practice to at least do some logging instead of exception handling. There are rare occasions were just swallowing the exception is considered appropriate.

Comment: Logging is not always wanted. But It's good to show your intention even in this case. At least to distinguish intended and unintended usage. Especially for analyzers.

Comment: I think logging is a good practice, if appropriate logging level is used. After all, exception, if not used incorrectly, indicates that something exceptional has occured.

Answer (score 2):

in order to keep the code up with your exception handling or ignoring, it's nice to name the exception var as `ignored`:

```
try {
  action();
} catch (ExpectedException ignored ) {}
```

Comment: Do your analyzers know about such conventions? My are not so smart, they will punish you for unintended ignore ;-).

Comment: I'm analyzing myself, thank you :) nevertheless, if this convention is missing, as well as a well-defined exception handlig/ingore strategy, they should be added to your company's Big Red Proccess Book

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your update referring to testing, if you use a testing framework, you can annotate the test in such a way that an exception is expected, e.g. using TestNG

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = ClassNotFoundException.class)
public void testSomething() {
   // will succeed if a ClassNotFoundException is thrown
}
```

Comment: Had such code long time ago, how about case where exception MUST be thrown but will not because of error? How if you can throw several exceptions and it depends on input data what exactly you get?